# How to read function parameters in API document?

Tags: javascript, function, api

https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Syntax

> new Error([message[, fileName[,lineNumber]]])

I always wondering what [ ... [, ... [, ...]]]] means.

It seemed not  arrays because it has "," inside of "[...]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every `[...]` means its content is optional *(only when describing a function signature somewhere, this ain't valid code)*

so `new Error([message[, fileName[,lineNumber]]])`

means `new Error();`
or `new Error(message);`
or `new Error(message, fileName);`
or `new Error(message, fileName, lineNumber);`

it does **not** allow for something like `new Error(lineNumber);`